# Receive a Cognito Form submission by email

Tags: cognito-forms

I just finished making a form in Cognito and would like to know if it is possible to receive a submission by email? If not is there an alternative way that I could send the responses by email?

Also wanted to ask if there is a way to collect data from the submissions we get.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a member of the [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/) team.

Yes, you can receive submissions by email in Cognito Forms. These are called notification emails. To enable this feature, open your form builder page and click "Submission Settings" at the bottom of the page. In the Submission Settings box that opens on the left, select an option called "Notification Emails". Here, you can fill in your email address and specify what other information you want to include in the email, such as entry details and attachments.

[image]

There are several things you can do with your form data after it has been submitted. You have the option to print it out, save it as a PDF file, export it to Excel, or integrate it with one of our [third-party apps](https://www.cognitoforms.com/features/integrations).